# Why the featured image after closing the popup moves up and I have no clue?

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

When I click the preview button on any of the listings. A popup is shown but when I close the popup the featured image of that listing moves up. I have checked the reason by inspecting the element but I am not sure why this is moving up?

This CSS code is for the main section in elementor.

```css
selector:hover #inner-section-listing {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  opacity: 1;
}

selector{
    overflow: hidden !important;
}

selector .elementor-widget-image{
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

This CSS code is for the black subsection which comes up on hover.

```css
selector{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    
  transform: translatey(55px);
  transition: transform 0.5s, opacity 0.7s  linear;
}
```

[Please check the live website](https://alex.fiveuptech.com/home/)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUOR8.jpg)

Comment: don't link to your page, post all code we need to the question itself. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it With the code you posted currently this is not enough information

Comment: Problem doesn't appear to be there anymore, what was the solution? I tried fixing it a couple of time between tasks but couldn't find it fast enough.